# What is wrong with my Insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x[] = { 9, 5, 8, 4, 3, 0, 6, 7, 2, 1 };
        int[] result = InsertionSortMethod(x);

        for (int z = 0; z < x.length; z++) {
            System.out.print(x[z] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] InsertionSortMethod(int x[]){
        for (int a = 0; a < x.length; a++) {
            int divider = a;
            if(divider > 0 & divider < x.length){
                if(x[divider] < x[0]){
                    int temp = x[divider];
                    for(int c = divider; c > 0; c--){
                        x[c] = x[c-1];
                    }
                    x[0] = temp;
                }
                if(x[divider] > x[divider-1]){
                    x[divider] = x[divider];
                }
                else{
                    for(int b = divider-1; b > 0; b--){
                        if(x[divider] < x[b]){
                            int temp = x[divider];
                            x[divider] = x[b];
                            x[b] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Do you have sample input & output that is failing?

Comment: No errors and here is the output: 0 3 4 5 8 6 7 2 1 9. I am trying to figure out why the whole array isn't being sorted properly.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to step through your code to see what it's doing. It's quite a valuable skill.

Comment: @user1804933 Staring at code is rarely a good debug technique. I've written a web page on how to debug, using a Java program as example. See (http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to do it yourself, so just this:

```
for(int b = divider-1; b > 0; b--){
    if(x[divider] < x[b]){
        int temp = x[divider];
        x[divider] = x[b];
        x[b] = temp;
    }
}
```

If the part of the array with indices smaller than `divider` is already sorted, and `x[divider]` is between `x[0]` and `x[1]`, for example (and `divider` larger than 3, say), then `x[divider] < x[divider-1]` and in that loop is immediately swapped into position `divider-1`. But then the value at index `divider` has just become larger than `x[b]` for `0 <= b <= divider-2` and no further swaps are done. One possible way to deal with that is to update `divider` after each swap, `divider = b;` inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple insertion sort function:

```
void insertionSort(int[] arr) {

      int i, j, newValue;

      for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

            newValue = arr[i];

            j = i;

            while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > newValue) {

                  arr[j] = arr[j - 1];

                  j--;

            }

            arr[j] = newValue;

      }

}
```